# General solution to this functional equation.

Tags: functional-analysis, integer-lattices

Let $\Lambda_8$ be the $E_8$ lattice.

The functional equation is:

$$f(a) = \sum\limits_{a=b+c} f(b)f(c)$$

Where $f(a)$ is defined only for points on the lattice $a\in \Lambda_8$

What would be a general solution? 
I can find at least one solution: $f(0)=1$, $f(a)=0$ for $a\neq 0$

Comment: $f(a)=0\;\forall\,a\in\Lambda_8$ works as a specific solution.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this for the lattice $\,\mathbb{Z}?$